# php - Using preg_match invalidate correct regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I made this regular expression: `\/film\/\d{4}\/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\/*$`
to match: stuffstuffstuff**/film/YYYY/moviename/**

So for example I need to match:http://www.mymovies.it/film/2013/moliereinbicicletta/

The Regular Expression is correct, since I tested it on [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/) and [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

I'm pretty sure the problem is about how php handles the regex or maybe of how preg-match works, but in particular I'm sure it has something to do about escaping slashes with backslashes.

This is the code you can use to have a better understanding of the problem:

```
if (preg_match("\/film\/\d{4}\/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\/*$", "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2013/moliereinbicicletta/")) {
    echo "It's working, Good!";
} else {
    echo "It's not working :'(";
}
```

It's almost 3 a.m. and I want to sleep, but I want to get this crap done as soon as possible, it's been already 4 hours of trying and trying :'(

Comment: You are escaping the start of the regex. http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php It should be `/\/film\/\d{4}\/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\/*$`

Comment: Sorry `\/film\/\d{4}\/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\/*$/` in this case. Missed the last `/` delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
if (preg_match("#\/film\/\d{4}\/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\/*$#", "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2013/moliereinbicicletta/")) {
                ^ here                                ^ and here
```

And if you don't use the `/` as a delimiter (pretty common), you don't need to escape it so you could rewrite it to:

```
if (preg_match("#/film/\d{4}/+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+/*$#", "http://www.mymovies.it/film/2013/moliereinbicicletta/")) {
```

Comment: In your lower regex you missed the `backslash` before the `/*$#`. ;)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Would you mind explaining me a little what are delimiters and how they work? The php.net [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) page is a little confusing

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani They just mark the start and the end so that you can distinguish your pattern modifiers from the regex.

Comment: @dollarvar I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @jeroen I need to sleep also ;) but if you compare your both regexes and take the upper one as right, you will see a missing `backslash`. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar I'm not escaping the forward slashes in the lower regex, that's the point of the lower one. And they're both supposed to be right.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$url = "stuffstuffstuff/film/2013/moviename/"

if (preg_match('%.*?/film/[\d]{4}/moviename/%sim', $url)) {
    echo "It's working, Good!";
} else {
    echo "It's not working :'(";
}
```